# Why does passing an object instance to the UI thread like this cause delays/hang ups?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, task, marshalling

I implemented the following callback method as part of my UI framework:

```
private void OnSystemMessage(string senderId, SystemMessage msg)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        ActivityLog.Add(msg);
    });
}
```

OnMessage may be invoked by a different than UI thread. However, calling it the first time takes several seconds. Later on the same delay is not observable anymore. I do not understand why that is the case.

`ActivityLog` is an `ObservableCollection` and the UI thread is the one of my WPF application.

Is there a better ways to accomplish the same goal?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "moving an object instance" in the title... there's no such concept. Perhaps the delay is due to loading UI resources or something similar? It's hard to know without more information. (Do you need Invoke, or would BeginInvoke work for you?)

Comment: sorry, I meant upon invoking `OnSystemMessage` for the first time it causes delays. Your bringing up `BeginInvoke` actually may have already answered the problem: I possibly have a blocking condition and BeginInvoke may work just fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you for the suggestion, Jon. It solved my problem.

Comment: @MattWolf you can call [Dispatcher.CheckAccess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx) to check if you need the `Invoke` or not....

Comment: @m0sa, interesting, thanks for that pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So most likely UI thread is busy with something when you first time call OnSystemMessage. For example, you might log some message on application startup, while application is busy with initial loading of interface. Then this call might delay a bit. Since you just do logging in this method - use non-blocking BeginInvoke call.